# Django query : "datetime + delta" as an expression

Tags: python, sql, django, datetime, timedelta

Well, my question is a bit as follows:

Suppose I have the next model, this is a simple case:

```
class Period(models.Model):
    name = CharField(... field specs here ...)
    start_date = DateTimeField(... field specs here ...)
    duration = ... don't know what field should i use but this has to hold a delta ...
```

I would like to retrieve objects where (start_date + duration) < now in a django query (i know i can, in python, test like my_date_time + a_time_delta < datetime.now(), but this is not the case ... i need it as part of the query).

How can i get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your quick answer is to subtract from your now datetime versus add from the model datetime like this:

```
.filter(start_date__lte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=duration))
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped me. Such really noob question i did xDDD.
But ... what if i need to compare against another field?

e.g.

.filter(start_date__lte=F('another_datetime_field')-timedelta(...)) is allowed?

**EDITED** : I'm sorry, but i need to get the duration from the model. This means: duration and start_date are both instance-specific.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that in a single query through the ORM.  I think your options are to either accept using two queries or to use an `extra` clause to put the date arithmetic appropriate to your database back end into the constraints.

Comment: yes ... i will try the ".extra(where=...)" i figured yesterday

Answer (score 2):

As your filter depends of two attributes of the same model, you would need to use an `F() expression` for the `duration` part and at the same time combine it with some sort of `timedelta`. That's not supported in the Django ORM at the moment.

You can use an `extra()` call, though. The disadvantage of this approach is that it is not database-agnostic. This is for PostgreSQL:

```
Period.objects.extra(
    where=["start_date + duration * INTERVAL '1 day' < %s"],
    params=[datetime.now()]
)
```

assuming that your duration is in days. If not, adjust accordingly.

Comment: Is there an equivalent way of doing it for different databases?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to avoid using `extra` in your Django ORM queries, so you can apply next workaround:

1) add calculated field and update it on each model's save (you should adjust save logic according to your logic)

```
class Period(models.Model):
    name = CharField()
    start_date = DateTimeField()
    duration = IntegerField(help_text='hours')
    end_date = DateTimeField()

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.end_date = self.start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=self.duration)
    super(Period, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

2) then use calculated field in your queries:

```
finished = Period.objects.filter(end_date__lt=datetime.datetime.now())
```