# Customize django filter model field

Tags: python, django, filter

I have a following model

```
class some_model(models.Model):
    some_date = models.DateTimeField()
    hours = models.IntegerField()
```

Get a current date

```
temp_date = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Now I want filter on django field someting like this

```
filter_date = some_date + add timedelta(hours)
```

and then use filter_date in django filter

```
some_model.objects.filter(filter_date__gte = temp_date)
```

Above query possible in django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with [custom `QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/#create-manager-with-queryset-methods). I would suggest to create custom filter method instead of overriding existing one.

**Update** Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/33916628/3627387
You can achieve it with using `extra`

```
class CustomQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def date_filter(self):
        # using
        return self.extra(where=["some_date + hours * INTERVAL '1 hour' >= %s"], params=[datetime.now()])

class some_model(models.Model):
    some_date = models.DateTimeField()
    hours = models.IntegerField()

    objects = CustomQuerySet.as_manager()

# And then in your code
some_model.objects.date_filter()
```

Comment: I want to add timedelta in model field (some_date+timedelta(hours)) and then use a gte filter on some_date (some_date+timedelta(hours) gte temp_date) something like this.

Comment: What is difference? Mathematically speaking `some_date+timedelta(hours)_gte=temp_date` is same as `some_date_gte=temp_date-timedelta(hours)`. But first one is impossible in django ORM. So that's why me and @table proposing you to do it this way.

Comment: hours is my model field so how can I pass this hours to date filter

Comment: @NIKHILRANE read updated answer. This is not currently possible in django. But you can use `extra` for this and use raw SQL

Answer (score 3):

One more elegant way is to create DataBase Function.

Assume that we have the model that is described below. And our goal is to filter all objects which are ended before now.

```
from django.db import models

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    date_start = models.DateTimeField()
    duration = models.FloatField()
```

DataBase function implementation:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import Func
from django.db.models import DateTimeField


class Interval(Func):
    function = 'INTERVAL'
    template = "(%(expressions)s * %(function)s '1 %(phylum)s')"

    def __init__(self, expression, phylum, **extra):
        output_field = extra.pop('output_field', DateTimeField())
        super(Interval, self).__init__(expression, output_field=output_field, phylum=phylum, **extra)
```

And use it. As the first param to Interval function you can pass as F('field_name') or Value() or some Python objects. As the second params it can be: 'second', 'minute', 'hour', 'day'.

```
objs = (SomeModel.objects.annotate(date_end=F('date_start') + Interval(F('duration'), 'hour')).
filter(date_end__lte=datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)))
```

- Tested: Django==1.8.15, Postgres:9.4.5
- This implementation will work only in Postgres, for another DB you should override relevant method: 'as_postgresql', 'as_oracle'

Answer (score 0):

The query that you suggested will fall with error due to the fact, that `filter_date` is not a field of the model.

From my point of view what you're trying to do is get objects that have some_date greater than `hours` ago. This is the query to achieve that:

```
some_model.objects.filter(
    some_date__gte=datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(hours=hours))
```

Comment: Yeah I know but I want to customize that model filed.

Comment: The `filter` method pretty much forms a `SQL` query to execute on the database. So the answer is that you can't use the lookup on the field that does not exist in the table of the database.